# Friend function can't access class variables and can't understand Namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

I thought that friend functions could access class variables as in how I try to do v.x, v.y, v.z in the << function. But it doesn't compile. It says it's unable to resolve identifier at those lines.

Also I'm trying to learn how to use namespaces. Even though I use the namespace vec in the implementation file I still have to include Vector:: before everything so what's the point?

Header file:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

namespace vec {

    class Vector {
    private:
        double x, y, z;

    public:
        Vector(double, double, double);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,  const Vector&);

    };

}

#endif  /* VECTOR_H */
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace vec;

//Constructor
Vector::Vector(double x1 = 0, double y1 = 0, double z1 = 0) {
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    z = z1;
}

//Have also tried adding vec:: and Vector:: before operator<< here.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector& v) {
    out<<"<"<<v.x<<", "<<v.y<<", "<<v.z<<">";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* does the error(s) say?

Comment: It says "Unable to resolve identifier x." Then the next line "Unable to resolve identifier y." And "Unable to resolve identifier z."

Answer (score 1):

Your compile error may relative to below issues:

- Default parameter only goes to function declaration not function
  definition, you are doing the other way around.
- Also, in Vector.cpp you should wrap up your class member function
  definitions in namespace instead of calling `using directive`.

Try:

Vector.h

```
#include <iostream>
class Vector {
    private:
        double x, y, z;

    public:
        Vector(double x1 = 0, double y1 = 0, double z1 = 0);
                        ^^              ^^             ^^
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,  const Vector&);

    };
```

Vector.cpp

```
namespace vec
{
   Vector::Vector(double x1, double y1, double z1)
   :x(x1), y(y1), z(z1)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I still haven't gotten an answer to my question.  Why can't my friend function access x, y, and z! I haven't even gotten as far as getting compiling errors because it can't see those variables.

Comment: what's your error message? it works on my compiler. Try to fix your code with my answer, see if you still get errors

Comment: The only error messages I get is this: "Unable to resolve identifier x. Unable to resolve identifier y. Unable to resolve identifier z."

Comment: out<<"<"<<v.x<<", "<<v.y<<", "<<v.z<<">";

Comment: have you wrapped up your cod with namespace vec in Vector.cpp?

Comment: Did you include iostream in Vector.h?

Comment: iostream is included in Vector.h.

Comment: don't call `using namespace vec;` in .cpp, do it the same as .h

Comment: What do you mean exactly by wrapping the code with vec? I have it say using namespace vec; in the .cpp. and the .h is wrapped with namespace vec { }

Comment: To me I don't get any errors except the ones I've said. My IDE won't let me try to compile unless it sees all the variables are defined in their scope.

Answer (score 1):

I believe part of the problem is that your vec.h doesn't have `#include <iostream>`, so the type `std::ostream` is unidentified in that file, and since that part is compiled before the vec.cpp main part, it fails to recognise your function.

You also need to put your `operator<<` into the namespace of `vec`. After all, you have asked for a friend function within that namespace.

With these two changes, your code compiles with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2`.

Answer (score 0):

The `friend std::ostream& operator<<` declaration appears in namespace `vec`, so the definition should be prefixed by `vec::`.  Your comment says you tried that - maybe you got confused by the other error messages billz documents, but you should reinstate `vec::operator<<` or surround it with `namespace vec { ... }`.

This creates an error like:

```
ns.cc: In function `int main()':
ns.cc:26: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << w'
ns.cc:19: note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const vec::Vec&)
ns.cc:10: note:                 std::ostream& vec::operator<<(std::ostream&, const vec::Vec&)
```